# String to Float: NumberFormatException

Tags: java, string, jsp, numberformatexception

I'm using jsp for storing dvds into a database

For price I chose to use float.
In the form I use the next approach:

```
<form method="POST">
...
  <td>
      <input type="text" name="dvdprice"/>
  </td>
...
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When trying to convert it from string to float I use this

```
String price = request.getParameter("dvdprice");
...
Float.valueOf(price)
```

And I get this exception:

```
SEVERE:   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9.99"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:582)
...
```

I've searched for this problem all over the place but I couldn't find a solution..
I used this technique to convert the numbers millions of times and I'm not sure why isn't working right now...

Any help?

Comment: Can you please show your actual code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception you're getting *isn't* from a call to `Float.parseFloat`. It's from a call to `Integer.parseInt`. Check the line number in the stack trace to find out where. I suspect you're parsing integers elsewhere, and you're just pulling the wrong value to parse.

Additionally, strongly consider using `BigDecimal` instead of either `float` or `double` to store currency values. (Binary floating point types don't play nicely with quantities which have a precise decimal representation.)

Comment: Yes that's the problem. From the stack trace, he is trying to parse `9.99` as integer.

Comment: Indeed I had in other place Integer.valueOf(someString) which was float..

I didn't payed attention and I've only focused on that line of code where I knew I was parsing the float..

Lack of attention..

Thanks Jon :)